# не срабатывает конструктор класса c++

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++

Я начал изучать шаблоны классов и столкнулся с тем, что конструктор класса не вызывается, несмотря на строчку

`Class<int> cl();`

Буду очень благодарен за помощь. Вот весь код:

```
template <typename T>
class Class
{
private:
    T* num;

public:
    Class()
    {
        cout << "Ok\n";
        num = new T [1];
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << num[0];
    }

};

int main()
{
    Class<int> cl();
    cl.print(); // Функция не выполнится из-за ошибки: выражение должно иметь тип класса
    return 0; 
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Class<int> cl;`. Не нужно никаких `new`.

Компилятор считает `Class<int> cl();` объявлением функции (без параметров, с возвращаемым типом `Class<int>`).